# How to link script directory in App Engine for python?

Tags: python

I have file app.yaml:

```
application: v2011
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

When i try to add:

```
application: v2011
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

  - url: /scripts
  static_dir: scripts

- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

It just can not display content of linked javascript file. In python file it is defined as `<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/java.js"></script>` What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A sample code below. It does a pattern matching and if found, looks for file in the static/ folder. The url is http://app-id.appspot.com/my-script.js - also check the logs output at appengine.google.com, posting that error message here helps too.

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(html|css|js|gif|jpg|png|ico))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*
  expiration: "1d"
```

btw, you may want to try the new python 2.7 while you are at it.